# Responding to Twilio WebHook with XML

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, twilio

I'm building a Web API 2 API to respond to Twilio webhooks. I've built a fairly standard endpoint, and I can see that Twilio hits it when I text my number there, but it's getting a 12300 - Invalid Content-Type - Invalid Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 supplied.

I found that Twilio requires XML in response, but uses an accept-header of */*, so my endpoint is defaulting to return JSON.

```
[Route("reply")]
[HttpPost]
public TwiMLResult TwilioSMS([FromBody]SmsRequest request)
{
    var requestBody = request.Body;

    var response = new MessagingResponse();
    if (requestBody == "hello")
        response.Message("Hi!");
    else
        response.Message("Invalid Input");

    return new TwiMLResult(response);
}
```

I've tried returning an HttpResponseMessage instead (as below), so I can specify XML, but I get a 12200 Schema Validation Warning - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'TwiMLResult' from Twilio instead.

```
HttpResponseMessage resp = Request.CreateResponse<TwiMLResult>(
        HttpStatusCode.OK, value: new TwiMLResult(response),
        formatter: Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

How can I force this controller/endpoint to return XML, but not affect my other controllers/endpoints (which should still return based on accept-header)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Try returning the `MessagingResponse` directly using a `XmlMediaTypeFormatter`:

```
return this.Request.CreateResponse(
    HttpStatusCode.OK, XElement.Parse(response), new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error on response.ToXml() - "'TwiML.ToXml' is inaccessible due to its protection level". However, I tried XElement.Parse(response.ToString()) and it worked - thanks!